# Safety of local network over VPN

Tags: linux, networking, security, vpn, openvpn

I have a Linux machine in a local network that uses an OpenVPN connection to reach the outside world. However, I know nothing about the VPN server itself and therefore I assume that whoever operates it can have malicious intentions. The Linux machine is assumed to be safe enough to be used in a public network (no open ports or services running, up to date software etc.) and the data transferred over the VPN is also encrypted itself or harmless.

What I am curious about is whether other devices (that are potentially not as well protected) are safe if they operate on the same local network as the Linux machine. Can the VPN connection be exploited to access other devices on the local network (on the client side)? Would it be possible for the VPN server to inject routing rules to the client that would permit such access? If so, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route injection and compromise of local pcs are two distinct topics.

First of all, let us establish who is the danger: one would surely be whoever controls the OpenVPN server. Anyone outside the OpenVPN will find it well nigh impossible to overcome OpenVPN's well-constructed mutual authentication and key exchange procedure. In other words, if you are using certificates to connect to your server, there is nothing an outside attacker can do. As of today, I am aware of no exploits against OpenVPN's RSA plus Diffie-Helman plus block cipher security.

A malicious owner of the server can do you a lot of damage, even without using route pushing. In fact, she controls  your ultimate routing, and she can use malicious DNS servers, re-routing to corrupt sites, and so on, on **her own site**, no need to push extraneous routes to the clients. That way, you would not even be aware of what is causing the damage.

Can she use a compromised pc to attack you? The answer is: why would she, if she already has a direct access channel to your pc?

The last question is: let us suppose someone with a compromised pc is on your LAN, can he attack you? It does not matter how the pc was compromised, it might be a laptop that was compromised elsewhere, or it was compromised while navigating thru the OpenVPN thru the usual channels.
This pc would have no problems attacking you: an attacker with an access channel to the compromised pc would see you as a local pc, something that be accessed without reference to the OpenVPN. All pcs, no matter what the OS is, have a local route, otherwise it would be impossible to connect to the printer, to the tv, to local shares, and so on. But local onnections do not pass thru the vpn, no matter which kind of vpn that is. Hence a compromised pc would be a danger to you, yes indeed.

VPNs are supposed to provide privacy and security, in the sense that no one can force-access it from outside, which OpenVPN does egregiously. But there are no defenses in place if someone on your LAN downloads and installs malicious software, the local LAN is as transparent as clear water. In fact, the only problem an attacker has would be to establish your true IP address; [one of my early answers on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/649621/how-to-determine-my-actual-external-ip-address-through-the-windows-command-line/649839#649839), and one I regretted, was exactly about how to do this. Apart from this, it is smooth sailing for an attacker.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I do understand the dangers of routing my data through the server. However, please assume that no important data exchange is done through the Linux machine connecting to the VPN server. Let's say the only purpose of that machine is to read news. Now, I also do not assume that there is a compromised device on the local network. But, imagine that besides the Linux machine, there is a NAS on the local network which provides access to important data without a password, but is only visible within the local network.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible for the VPN server to access the unprotected NAS (without first finding some way of hacking into the Linux machine)?

Comment: @And Yes, that's exactly true. In the case in your comment, your Linux machine is the only conduit to the NAS, hence an attacker must first hack into the Linux pc, then from there it can move on to the LAN pcs, including NAS.

Comment: @And BTW, in Linux you can easily control this by using iptables to prevent forwarding from the VPN to the LAN, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not in control of the network you connected, so It is not the question of whether the VPN is secure or not. Question is the party who manages the network is trusted or not. 
For the individual answers to your questions

- No, VPN server cannot inject any client side routing to clients. But can route your traffic to different routes.
- Yes, VPN server can grant access to local network, but also any other device that can connect you to internet (Serving NATed connections to public networks)

None of these does make your devices more or less secure than they are.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. Normally other devices on my local network would be separated from the outside world using the NAT on the router. How does that situation compare to a situation when one of the devices in the local network connects to a VPN server? I can imagine a situation when the VPN server can access my local network by pushing a route that enables routing the internal IP addresses to the server. You say that VPN cannot inject any client side routing, how about the `push` command of openvpn?