# Can i use different network for different applications in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, gateway

I have ubuntu 16.04
I have installed VPN in there to download stuff.

Now i have application rclone which uploads data to amazon.

Is it possible that rclone does not use VPN but all other application does use it

Comment: iptables should be able to handle this, let me brush up on my iptable-ing and try to answer in a bit

Comment: You mean the `diff` program? Like `diff` over a network or vpn or something? I'm guessing no, but then the title is vauge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In absolute generality, it is **not** possible to set a route per application, even in modern pcs. **However**, there is a large number of *partial* solutions to this problem, of different degrees of complexity.

Luckily for you, your case is the **simplest** one possible, because basically you have one application that connects always to the same IP address. You do it as follows. Suppose, after having started the VPN, you have a routing table as follows:

```
# ip route show
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.73.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.73.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.73.66  metric 100 
IPAddress.Of.Remote.VPN.Server via 192.168.73.1 dev eth0
```

and that your application, *rclone* wants to connect to a server with IP address *1.2.3.4*. All you have to do is to add a route thru your default gateway (*i.e*, the one **without** VPN, *192.168.73.1* above) to *1.2.3.4*:

```
sudo ip route add 1.2.3.4/32 via 192.168.73.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.73.66
```

(where I have used my interface, which is called *eth0*, and my pc's IP address, *192.168.73.66*, you will have to adapt these to your specific case). This simply instructs the routing table to bypass your virtual interface, which is called *tun0* above but might be *tap0*, *ppp0*, or something like this in your case.

Actually, the principle used is the same I used in  [this](https://superuser.com/a/649839/255732) similar, though apparently unrelated, answer.

Comment: Thanks that was excellent. My now issue is amazon uses different ip based on location. Without vpn it the dns resolves to ip1 and i added that in route. But if VPN is on it will resolve to ip2 bceuase of location 2. so uploader will be slower and it will defy the use of other card

Comment: @Moorage Sorry, I do not understand. Since you are not using VPN for *rclone*, you should always use ip1, the resolved address obtained without VPN. And Amazon will know nothing because it will see rclone coming from your true IP address, not the VPN's. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @problem is  rclone upload to e.g Google via `api.google.com/upload` rclone does not use ip address to upload. My VPN will always be on so, dns will convert api.google.com to ip2  not ip1 unless dns resolution goes via eth0 not vpn

Comment: @Moorage No big problem: in the file */etc/hosts*, add a line of the form: *1.2.3.4 api.google.com* where, instead of 1.2.3.4, you use the IP address you called ip1 above. This way the DNS thru the VPN will not be queried. Also, remember you could always override the VPN DNS, if you want.